# ConcurrentModificationException when I am trying to edit ArrayList with iterator

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've got an ArrayList of Object and I am trying to edit the field of one of those object, but when I do it I am receiving ConcurrentModificationException  . I've read that I need to use Iterator, but even with this I am still receiving the error message.

My code:

```
if(summedEmotionValuesArrayList.size() == 0){
    summedEmotionValuesArrayList.add(newEmotionValuesDataset);
}else {
    for (Iterator<EmotionValuesDataset> currentEmotionValuesDataset = summedEmotionValuesArrayList.iterator(); currentEmotionValuesDataset.hasNext(); ) {
        EmotionValuesDataset emotionValuesDataset = currentEmotionValuesDataset.next();
        if (emotionValuesDataset.getEmotionName().equals(newEmotionValuesDataset.getEmotionName())) {
            double newValue = emotionValuesDataset.getEmotionValue() + newEmotionValuesDataset.getEmotionValue();
            emotionValuesDataset.setEmotion_value(newValue);
        } else {
            summedEmotionValuesArrayList.add(newEmotionValuesDataset);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is executed multiple times within a for loop. The error message is occurring on this line

> EmotionValuesDataset emotionValuesDataset = currentEmotionValuesDataset.next();

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
summedEmotionValuesArrayList.add(newEmotionValuesDataset);
```

this line making problems, You should create some other lists (name it yourTempList) and add elements there, after exit for loop just use

```
summedEmotionValuesArrayList.addAll(yourTempList)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to basically add the values to the arraylist `summedEmotionValuesArrayList`. If you look into the way `add` is implemented,

```
    public void add(E e) {
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            int i = cursor;
            ArrayList.this.add(i, e);
            cursor = i + 1;
            lastRet = -1;
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }
```

And, if you look at the implementation of `checkForComodification()`, you can see that it checks `modCount`.

So, based on that, and documentation of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html, you can see this following.

> If the value of this field changes unexpectedly, the iterator (or list
>   iterator) will throw a ConcurrentModificationException in response to
>   the next, remove, previous, set or add operations. This provides
>   fail-fast behavior, rather than non-deterministic behavior in the face
>   of concurrent modification during iteration.

Therefore, the way you can solve this is by,creating a new temp list. This has been already answered. Anyway,

```
    ArrayList<EmotionValuesDataset> tempList = new ArrayList();

    for(...){
        //use your logic, but instead of  summedEmotionValuesArrayList.add(newEmotionValuesDataset);
        tempList.add(newEmotionValuesDataset);

    }

    //outside of forloop
    summedEmotionValuesArrayList.addAll(tempList)
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

While iterating over an ArrayList, the iterator is always checking the modCount to the value it saved on the start of the iteration. This value changes with every add, remove, set, ... and if it changes during an iteration a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

If you want to remove the item you are currently on you can use the Iterator#remove method, which knows to updated the expectedModCount. As you are adding values to the ArrayList, you can save them in a temporary list and then, when the iteration is over, add all of those elements to the original list.

```
for(...) {
    ...
    temp.add(newValue);
    ...
}
summedEmotionValuesArrayList.addAll(temp);
```